# Converting SimpleCursorAdapter code from Java to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to reuse the following Java code in Kotlin:

```
        SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.textsummarylistentry, mMatrixCursor, 
                from, to);
        setListAdapter(scAdapter);
```

When I copy and paste this into a Kotlin class which extends ListActivity, and accept Android Studio's automatic conversion to Kotlin I get the following:

```
        var scAdapter : android . widget . SimpleCursorAdapter ? =
                SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.textsummarylistentry, mMatrixCursor,
                    from, to
                )
        listAdapter = scAdapter
```

There are numerous errors which Quick Fix is unable to resolve. How should I correct this code?

Comment: Replace `android . widget . SimpleCursorAdapter ?` with `SimpleCursorAdapter`, or even just remove it and the preceding colon (so it becomes `var scAdapter = ...`). Beyond that, since we have no access to the rest of your code, it will be difficult for us to advise you without knowing the specific errors that you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. When I tried your suggestions and the errors didn't go away I noticed that I had inadvertently deleted a closing parenthesis on the previous line. Sorry I wasted your time. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Since you accepted an answer, I do not think that you will be able to delete the question. I am glad that you got things working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
var scAdapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.textsummarylistentry, mMatrixCursor, from, to)
setListAdapter(scAdapter)
```

Share the error message if this doesn't works.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. When I tried your suggestion and the errors didn't go away I noticed that I had inadvertently deleted a closing parenthesis on the previous line. Sorry I wasted your time. Should I delete the question?